# Is it possible to view password of firebase sign-in users with email and password in our app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have built an app in flutter and have used firebase email password auth method for users login.
I just wanted to know that can we view the password of our users in firebase.
If it is not possible to view our app's user's password, then it might be injustice, as we are the owners of app and we ourselves do not know the password of our app users.
For example, facebook app owners (zuckerberg) might be knowing their users' password, or instagram app owners might be knowing their users' password. So, as app owners we must also know our app users' password for security purposes.
So is it possible to know users' password in firebase email password sign-in method.
By the way, I am a complete beginner in programming, and please ignore any mistakes above (or anything I have said incorrect above).

Comment: _"...it might be injustice, as we are the owners of app and we ourselves do not know the password of our app users."_ I disagree. And often passwords are not even persisted, but just a hash value which (if "salted") can not (easily or at all) be converted back to the actual password. So, Zuckerberg might not know your Instagram password. But then again, he doesn't need it to view all your data. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are u storing the user and password in firebase authentication then no it is not possible to view the password written by the user. You can store the password in the database but if someone got access to your database they can know all the passwords of the users using your application.

There is no need to know the password of the user, if you want to `reauthenticate` or `updatePassword` then you can use the methods provided here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

Comment: but does it means that Google(firebase) knows all the passwords and they can misuse it as well ?

Comment: when you create a user and you pass a plain password, the password then gets encrypted by firebase but no they won't misuse it..

Comment: is there any safer alternative in which we have all the control?

Comment: This is the safest way, many companies have created projects using firebase without any problem. If you want access to the password then add them to the firebase database but I'm telling you that is not safe at all.